# Изменить значение String - Java, Android

Tags: java, android, webview, search

Я пишу свой браузер и столкнулся с проблемой. Решил реализовать выбор поискового агрегата, например Google, Яндекс, Mail.ru и т.д.. Сам выбор реализую через PreferenceFragmentCompat, через элемент ListPreference. Теперь сама суть вопроса. Как можно менять значение строки String? Код ниже:

```
String url = ""; // Тут нужно менять значение строки
String google = "https://google.com/search?q="; // Одна из строк для замены значения
String yandex = "https://yandex.ru/search/?text=";
String mail = "https://go.mail.ru/search?q=";
    
    // Код из onResume
    String search = mSharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.title_search), "0");

    if (search.contains(getString(R.string.google))) {
        url = google;
    }

    if (search.contains(getString(R.string.yandex))) {
        url = yandex;
    }

    if (search.contains(getString(R.string.mail))) {
        url = mail;
    }
```

P.S. Буду благодарен любому ответу или наводке. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а что с этим кодом не так?

Comment: @Эникейщик он не работает. Не меняет значение String

Comment: Совершенно верно. Потому что строки в яве - неизменяемые!

Comment: Правильно ли я понял проблему: переменная url используется много где, и сначала в другом месте вы обработали url, получили какой-то результат, запомнили, затем меняете url в приведенном коде, а в том "другом месте" значение не изменилось, так?

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий вот, всё правильно. Да, именно так и есть

Comment: `mSharedPreferences` как получен - `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`, надеюсь? Так же не ясна суть проблемы - что значит не работает? Опишите как должно быть, что происходит сейчас и при каких обстоятельствах.

Comment: @woesss во фрагменте настроек я использую этот код: `ListPreference listPreference = findPreference(getString(R.string.title_search));
        if (listPreference.getValue() == null) {
            listPreference.setValueIndex(0);
        }

        listPreference.setSummary(listPreference.getValue());
        listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener((preference, newValue) -> {
            preference.setSummary(newValue.toString());
            return true;
        });` но он не играет роли. А выше описанный код в основном активити в onResume. Чтобы сохранить настройки

Comment: Всё равно информации не достаточно для дельного совета. Что касается строк - они не изменяются. `url = google;` - так вы меняете не саму строку, а переменную - теперь она указывает на другую строку. Что бы код в другом месте увидел это изменение он должен обратиться непосредственно к этой переменной, а не когда-то сделанной копии, по-прежнему ссылающейся на старую строку. И, естественно, обращение должно происходить не раньше, чем сработает `onResume` в вашем случае

Comment: @woesss а можно пример кода? Либо я готов с вами обсудить более подробно в любых мессенджерах. Если у вас телеграм, то возможно ли обсудить более подробно с вами именно там?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз я прав, как вы сказали в комментариях, то вы немного не в ту сторону копаете. Вам нужна подписочная модель. Можно приплести какой-нибудь LiveData или rxJava, если будет не лень, но в самом простом виде это будет выглядеть так же, как работа с OnClickListener или OnLayoutChangeListener

```
Создаем интерфейс 
interface OnUrlChangeListener(){
    void onUrlChange(newUrl: String);
}
```

в месте, где вам нужно как-то обрабатывать ссылку меняем прямое использование поля url на реализацию этого интерфейса. То есть во фрагменте вместо

```
@override
public void onViewCreated(...){
    ...
    webView.loadUrl(yourObject.url);
}
```

надо сделать следующее:

```
public class MyFragment() extends Fragment(), OnUrlListener{
   @Override
   public void onUrlChange(newUrl: String){ //этот метод будет отрабатывать каждый раз, когда url меняется
       if(isAdded() && webView != null){
           webView.loadUrl(newUrl);
       }
   }
   
   @Override
   public void onCreate(...){
       yourObject.addUrlChangeListener(this) //при создании подписываемся на получение значения url
   }
}
```

и теперь остается добавить логику в этот самый yourObject, чем бы он ни был

```
private String mUrl = "";
private ArrayList<OnUrlChangeListener> listeners = new ArrayList<OnUrlChangeListener>();

    public void addUrlChangeListener(listener: OnUrlChangeListener){
       listeners.add(listener); //собираем из всех подписавшихся список подписчиков
       listener.onChangeUrl(mUrl) //опционально. после того как кто-то подписался сразу можно сообщить ему текущее значение, можно дожидаться появление нового. Первый путь обычно правильный, но всякое бывает.
    }
    
    public void setUrl(newUrl: String){
   if(newUrl.contentEquals(mUrl))
      return;
   mUrl = newUrl;
   for(OnChangeUrlListener l: listeners){ //перебираем всех подписчиков и сообщаем об изменении
      l.onChangeUrl(mUrl)
   }
}
```

теперь в случае изменения значения url у вас везде, где оно используются, будут происходить какие-то действия. Это лишь грубый пример чтобы можно было уловить суть. Надо еще научить отписываться тем, кто уже подписался, следить за утечками, доступностью, жизненным циклом элементов и еще пару нюансов. Крайне рекомендую. разобраться с LiveData, может даже с ViewModel, они могут сильно упростить отслеживание подписок и сохранению доступности

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так, конечно

```
if (search.contains(getString(R.string.google))) {
    String url = google;
}
и т.д.
```

и убрать `String url = "";` в начале. Но это не очень красивое решение.

Comment: если есть не очень красивое решение, значит есть и красивое решение :) Проблема ещё в чём заключается, а в том, что я не могу просто так выкинуть `String url = "";`, так как тогда закладки работать не будут. Да и как тогда будет грузиться страница в WebView, если я пропишу только в onResume.